# Why is a char array of size 2 printing more than 2 characters?

Tags: arrays, c, char, scanf, allocation

Why are some ***grade*** ***(Hurup Mutu)*** column items getting printed with the ***mark*** ***(Angka Mutu)*** column items (for example ***`B+3,5`*** where ***B+*** is the ***grade*** and ***3,5*** is the ***mark***), even though in my `data struct`, I have defined the ***grade*** ***(Hurup Mutu)*** char array to have only 2 characters, but it's storing up to 5.

This doesn't occur on every line, so I'm having a hard time finding the error, please help me.

You can see it in the following output, I have highlighted the results that are wrong:

[image: Output]

This is my C Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data
{
    char nim[13];
    char nama[50];
    float uts, uas, tugas, kuis,total;
    char grade[2], angka[4], status[14];
};

void tampil();
void data(struct data[], int );
char* hurupMutu(int);
char* nilaiMutu(int);
char* status(int);

int main() {

    tampil();

    return 0;
}

void tampil(){
    int p;
    char *a;

    printf("+----------------------------------+\n");
    printf("|       Masukan Data Mahasiswa     +\n");
    printf("+----------------------------------+\n");

    printf("Masukan Banyak Data Mahasiswa : ");
    scanf("%d", &p);

    if (p < 1){
        printf("Data Mahasiswa harus lebih besar dari 0 ");
        exit(0);
    }

    struct data d[p];

    for(int i = 0; i < p; i++){
        int total = 0;
        
        printf("Data ke %d : \n", i+1);
        
        printf("Masukan NIM : ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(d[i].nim);
        
        printf("Masukan Nama : ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(d[i].nama);
        
        printf("Masukan Nilai UTS : ");
        scanf("%f", &d[i].uts);
        total +=  d[i].uts * 0.3;
    
        printf("Masukan Nilai UAS : ");
        scanf("%f", &d[i].uas);
        total += d[i].uas * 0.3;
        
        printf("Masukan Nilai Tugas : ");
        scanf("%f", &d[i].tugas);
        total += d[i].tugas * 0.2;
    
        printf("Masukan Nilai Kuis : ");
        scanf("%f", &d[i].kuis);
        total += d[i].kuis * 0.2;
        d[i].total = total;
      
        strcpy(d[i].grade, hurupMutu(d[i].total));
        strcpy(d[i].status, status(d[i].total));
        strcpy(d[i].angka, nilaiMutu(d[i].total));
    }
  
    data(d, p);
}

char* hurupMutu(int a){
    if (a >= 80 && a <= 100){
      return "A";
    }else if(a >= 70 && a < 80){
      return "B+";
    }
    else if(a >= 65 && a < 70){
      return "B";
    }else if(a >= 60 && a < 65){
      return "C+";
    }else if(a >= 55 && a < 60){
      return "C";
    }else if(a >= 50 && a < 55){
      return "D+";
    }else if(a >= 45 && a < 50){
      return "D";
    }else if( a < 45){
      return "E";
    }else{
      return "?";
    }
}



char* nilaiMutu(int a){
    if (a >= 80 && a <= 100){
      return "4,0";
    }else if(a >= 70 && a < 80){
      return "3,5";
    }else if(a >= 65 && a < 70){
      return "3,0";
    }else if(a >= 60 && a < 65){
      return "2,5";
    }else if(a >= 55 && a < 60){
      return "2,0";
    }else if(a >= 50 && a < 55){
      return "1,5";
    }else if(a >= 45 && a < 50){
      return "1,0";
    }else if( a < 45){
      return "0";
    }else{
      return "?";
    }
}

char* status(int a){
    if (a >= 80 && a <= 100){
      return "Istimewa";
    }else if(a >= 70 && a < 80){
      return "Sangat Baik";
    }
    else if(a >= 65 && a < 70){
      return "Baik";
    }else if(a >= 60 && a < 65){
      return "Cukup Baik";
    }else if(a >= 55 && a < 60){
      return "Cukup";
    }else if(a >= 50 && a < 55){
      return "Kurang Cukup";
    }else if(a >= 45 && a < 50){
      return "Kurang";
    }else if( a < 45){
      return "Sangat Kurang";
    }else{
      return "Tidak Tau";
    }
}


void data(struct data d[], int p){

    printf("+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("| NO |    NIM     |     Nama  | Total Nilai | Hurup Mutu | Angka Mutu | Gabungan Kemampuan |\n");
    printf("+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < p; i++){
        printf("| %d  ", i + 1);
        
        int a = strlen(d[i].nim);
        int b = 10 - a;
        
        printf("| %s ", d[i].nim);
        for(int j = 0; j < b; j ++){
            printf(" ");
        }
    
        int c = strlen(d[i].nama);
        int e = 50 - c;
    
        printf("| %s", d[i].nama);
        
        for(int j = 0; j < e; j ++){
            printf(" ");
        }
    
        printf(" |");
        printf(" %.2f       " ,d[i].total);

        int f = strlen(d[i].grade);
        int g = 12 - f;
    
        printf("| %s" ,d[i].grade);
        
        for(int j = 0; j < g; j++){
            printf(" ");
        }

        int h = strlen(d[i].angka);
        int k = 12 - h;
    
        printf("| %s" ,d[i].angka);
    
        for(int j = 0; j < k; j ++){
            printf(" ");
        }

        int l = strlen(d[i].status);
        int m = 20 - l;
    
        printf("| %s" ,d[i].status);
    
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j ++){
            printf(" ");
        }
    
        printf("|\n");
        printf("+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Also see this: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/1553090)

Comment: See also: [c - Using fflush(stdin) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin)

Comment: regarding: `fflush(stdin);``the `fflush` function is for output streams only altho some poor compilers (microsoft comes to mind)  do allow it.

Answer (score 6):

`char grade[2]` is too short to store 2-character strings like `"B+"` because there are no room for the terminating null-character.

Allocate enough space to avoid errors.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's work, I got a new lesson today

Answer (score 2):

For starters this call of `fflush`

```
fflush(stdin);
```

has undefined behavior. Remove it.

The function gets used in your program as for example

```
gets(d[i].nim);
```

is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard. Instead either use `scanf` or `fgets`. For example

```
scanf( " %12[^\n]", d[i].nim );
```

(Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters.)

Using the variable `total` declared as having the type `int`

```
int total = 0;
```

with values of the type `float` like

```
total +=  d[i].uts * 0.3;
total += d[i].uas * 0.3;
total += d[i].tugas * 0.2;
total += d[i].kuis * 0.2;
```

and then assigning its value to the data member `total` that has the type float

```
float uts, uas, tugas, kuis,total;
```

does not make a great sense. At least it is unclear why the local variable `total` declared with the type `int`.

Also all these functions `hurupMutu`, `status`, and `nilaiMutu` have parameters of the type `int`

```
  strcpy(d[i].grade, hurupMutu(d[i].total));
  strcpy(d[i].status, status(d[i].total));
  strcpy(d[i].angka, nilaiMutu(d[i].total));
```

but are called with argument expressions of the type `float`.  So either declare the data member total as having the type `int` or redeclare parameters of the functions as having the type `float`.

The data member grade is declared as an array of 2 elements

```
char grade[2], angka[4], status[14];
```

but the function `hurupMutu` can return a string of 3 elements (including the terminating zero character `'\0'` of a string literal) like for example

```
return "B+";
```

In this case using the function `strcpy` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working, I got a new lesson today, next time I won't be using gets(). related "  strcpy(d[i].grade, hurupMutu(d[i].total));" integer value inside which is the index for the array of my struct